# Angular 2 Routing 404 error

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Hello I am trying to route to a different screen from the homepage using Angular 2. However when I am getting a 404 error that reads:

**GET http://localhost:5000/map/1 404 (Not Found)**

The application integrates ASP.NET Core on the backend.

Two questions:

(1) Do I need a method in a MVC controller as well that says something like

```
[Route("api/map")]
public IActionResult Map()
{
    return View();
}
```

(2) Is there something wrong with my angular routing?

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { UniversalModule } from 'angular2-universal';
import { AppComponent } from './components/app/app.component'
import { NavMenuComponent } from './components/navmenu/navmenu.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';
import { FetchDataComponent } from './components/fetchdata/fetchdata.component';
import { MapComponent } from './components/map/map.component';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
    { path: 'map/:id', component: MapComponent },
    { path: 'fetch-data', component: FetchDataComponent },
    { path: '**', redirectTo: 'home' }
];

@NgModule({
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        NavMenuComponent,
        MapComponent,
        FetchDataComponent,
        HomeComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        UniversalModule, 
        RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
    ]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

map.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MapService } from './../map.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'map-root', 
    templateUrl: 'map.component.html',
    providers: [MapService]
})

export class MapComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(public _mapService: MapService) { }
    public images: [any];
    ngOnInit() {

    }

}
```

map.component.html

```
<h1>This is a test</h1>
```

Index.html

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}

<base href="/" />
<app class="container" style="display: block;">Loading...</app>
<script src="~/dist/vendor.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
@section scripts {
    <script src="~/dist/main-client.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
}
```

web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

  <!--
    Configure your application settings in appsettings.json. Learn more at https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=786380
  -->

  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="AngularJS Routes" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.html" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Angular docs cover this here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/visual-studio-2015.html#!#build-and-run

and here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/deployment.html#!#server-configuration

This is a snippet:

> For apps that use routing If your app uses routing, you need to teach
>   the server to always return index.html when the user asks for an HTML
>   page for reasons explained in the Deployment guide.
>
> Everything seems fine while you move about within the app. But you'll
>   see the problem right away if you refresh the browser or paste a link
>   to an app page (called a "deep link") into the browser address bar.
>
> You'll most likely get a 404 - Page Not Found response from the serer
>   for any address other than / or /index.html.
>
> You have to configure the server to return index.html for requests to
>   these "unknown" pages. The lite-server development server does
>   out-of-the-box. If you've switched over to F5 and IIS, you have to
>   configure IIS to do it. This section walks through the steps to adapt
>   the QuickStart application.

Comment: This makes perfect sense. My <base href="/" /> element was in the Layout View not the Index. However I have implemented the code suggested in your docs and am STILL getting the error. I have added the edits to my post. Any insight would be wonderful. Thx

Comment: Hi RyeGuy, Did you get this working. I'm facing the same problem, after moving the application to the server. It works fine if I access index.html, like so: `myserver.com/appVirtualDir/index.html`.  If I try to directly access routes (`myserver.com/appVirtualDir/mainview`), it shows 404.